# Angular chosen tabindex bug

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I'm using angular chosen directive , everything works well , except tabindex , when i switch between field , it jumps from select list that created by chosen .

i'm using ui router + ng-switch in this form . also i've created a plunkr to prove that but Unfortunately it works in plunkr . :)
What would you suggest ?
Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/c9rNCLcEf8dCc9M7BlPD?p=preview

```
Chosen : Version 1.0.0  
  <select tabindex="2" chosen disable-search="false"
  no-results-text="'Tough luck'"
  ng-model="bar">
    <option>Hi</option>
    <option>This is fun</option>
    <option>I like Chosen so much</option>
    <option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

Comment: In the plunker link, the tab index is working fine. After first text box, it is moving onto the select box only. Press down arrow, then you will get the list of options.

Are you expecting something else?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work in my project , i don't know why !!!
i'm also using ng-switch and ui router

Comment: Check if there are any errors on your console?

Comment: no there is no error , but in chosen.jquery how can i prevent to set tab  = -1;

Comment: Try update to Angular [Chosen 1.4.0](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/releases/tag/1.4.0) I believe it'll work.